# programmatically check if view includes specific layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-include

I have a layout `section.xml` and some other layouts that may include `section.xml`.

Now suppose I have an inflated layout, for example `layout.xml`, and I want to know does it include `section.xml` or not?

I can loop through all children of `layout.xml`, but I do not know how I can detect if a child is `section.xml` that is included here or not. I know I can try to set a unique id for `section.xml` and check ids of children of `layout.xml`, but the problem is the *uniqueness*; because other developers may forget this rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now suppose I have an inflated layout, for example layout.xml, and I want to know does it include section.xml or not?

That is not possible, in any direct fashion. Once a layout resource is inflated, there are no signs of the layout resource itself. This is both for direct inflation (e.g., `inflate()` that you call) and indirect inflation (e.g., `<include>` in a layout to pull in another layout).

> I know I can try to set a unique id for section.xml

I am interpreting this as meaning "set a unique ID for a widget inside of section.xml". That is the closest thing that you can do at runtime that resembles the rule that you are trying to implement.

> and check ids of children of layout.xml, but the problem is the uniqueness; because other developers may forget this rule.

Then your ID was not unique enough. :-) Use diceware to come up with something that nobody else will use by accident, such as `android:id="aquamarineBakeryUprightAnxietyPlugAlchemy"`. Ideally, use this on a widget that you do not need to reference from elsewhere in the layout or from your code.

Alternatively, implement a Lint rule to check things at compile time. In Lint processing, layout resources are still layout resources. So, if certain layout resources must `<include>` your `section` layout, you can confirm that via a Lint rule. Or, if certain layout resources must not `<include>` your `section` layout, you can confirm that too. Unfortunately, writing Lint rules is not that well documented.